# Why is there so much whitespace (carriage returns) at the bottom of Command Prompt and Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I've always wondered why the Command Prompt and Powershell both have so many carriage returns preloaded when you run each of the applications. You can scroll forever and ever (ok, not really, but several dozen, if not hundreds of page lengths of empty space). I don't have my Unix machine right now, but I'm pretty sure Terminal doesn't have that padding.

I have tried searching for a reason, but I have come up empty. It's not exactly a bug, so I guess not many people are searching for an answer.

Comment: This sounds like a task for [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)

Comment: Why do you need to know the answer? (What will you do with the information once you get it?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Nothing. Purely for curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be referring to the screen buffer size as described here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/03/12/powershell-screen-buffer-size.aspx?m=1

This article explains it in more detail:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx

> When a screen buffer is created, it contains blanks. Its cursor is
>   visible and positioned at the buffer's origin (0,0), and the window is
>   positioned with its upper left corner at the buffer's origin. The size
>   of the console screen buffer, the window size, the text attributes,
>   and the appearance of the cursor are determined by the user or by the
>   system defaults.

Unix works in a slightly different way, via a scrollback buffer, as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145050/what-exactly-is-scrollback-and-scrollback-buffer

Comment: No, the question is not about how to *set* the buffer size. It's asking *why* the buffer is scrollable down, even if there isn't any content yet. Usually buffer becomes scrollable when there is enough stuff in it.

Comment: My assumption is that's how the buffer works, it makes that amount of empty space available to be filled.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like once the user sets the buffer size, the lines will be available to be scrolled through with or without content. I think vonPryz was implying that that doesn't answer why it was implemented that way (as in, was there a reason they couldn't trim the whitespace if there was no content?). I suppose that's a finer detail and you answered the heart of the question.